# SAML RSA & AES Decryption - Random Junk Bytes At End

Tags: java, encryption, aes, saml, shibboleth

SAML XML responses are encrypted by our Gluu/Shibboleth server with my public cert. I have read the spec, and with the help of Stackoverflow, implemented the solution. However, upon decryption, I get random characters at the end.

SAML responses use an RSA-ECB/MGF1 encoded AES-128-CBC key. So first I have to decode the AES key (bytes) and then use that AES key to decrypt the XML response.

Here is my code:

```
public static void main(String[] args) throws Exception {
    Path p = Paths.get("C:\\Users\\jj\\Desktop\\myPrivateKey.key");
    String encryptedAESKey = "FUZLPtkLSUgOo0bETQ5hwP1OWNggGlWhG+Z......wF1G6twRjg=="; // from XML
    byte[] aesKey = decryptWithPem("RSA/ECB/OAEPwithSHA1andMGF1Padding", "RSA", Util.base64DecodeAsBytes(encryptedAESKey), p);
    String encryptedXML = "YfJu7h4Id09hpuoqthl3Ks/JqhIXm.....amb24JZu7cJZT3cEO2a2U6qi0VCyoXQ=";
    byte[] decryptedData = decrypt("AES/CBC/NoPadding", "AES", Util.base64DecodeAsBytes(encryptedXML), aesKey);
    for(int i = decryptedData.length - 20; i < decryptedData.length; i++) {
        System.out.println("i: " + i + " -> " + decryptedData[i]); // print last 20 bytes
    }
    System.out.println(new String(decryptedData)); // prints <saml2:Assertion xmlns:saml2="urn:oasis:names:........</saml2:Assertion>�G{A

}
```

**Note that random bytes on the print statement!** Last line prints:

`<saml2:Assertion xmlns:saml2="urn:oasis:names:........</saml2:Assertion>�G{A`

I realized that the first 16 bytes in the message are the IV, so I strip them from the message (getting rid of the junk from the beginning of the message). But now I get random 5 bytes at the end of the message. Those bytes are:

```
i: 1931 -> -120
i: 1932 -> 71
i: 1933 -> 123
i: 1934 -> 65
i: 1935 -> 5
```

Other functions:

```
public static byte[] decryptWithPem(String alg, String pemAlg, byte[] encryptedData, Path pemPath) {
    try {
        Cipher cipher = Cipher.getInstance(alg, "BC");
        cipher.init(Cipher.DECRYPT_MODE, loadPrivateKey(pemPath, pemAlg));
        return cipher.doFinal(encryptedData);
    } catch (Exception e) {
        throw new RuntimeException(e);
    }
}

private static PrivateKey loadPrivateKey(Path keyPath, String alg) {
    try {
        byte[] keyData = Util.base64DecodeAsBytes(IOUtil.fileToString(keyPath).replaceAll("\\s", ""));
        KeyFactory keyFactory = KeyFactory.getInstance(alg);
        EncodedKeySpec privateKeySpec = new PKCS8EncodedKeySpec(keyData);
        return keyFactory.generatePrivate(privateKeySpec);
    } catch(NoSuchAlgorithmException | InvalidKeySpecException e) {
        throw new RuntimeException(e);
    }
}

private static SecretKeySpec getSecretKeySpec(String alg, byte[] key) {
    return new SecretKeySpec(key, alg);
}

public static byte[] decrypt(String alg, String keyAlg, byte[] dataToDecrypt, byte[] key) {
    try {
        Cipher cipher = Cipher.getInstance(alg, "BC");
        cipher.init(Cipher.DECRYPT_MODE, getSecretKeySpec(keyAlg, key), new IvParameterSpec(dataToDecrypt, 0, 16));
        return cipher.doFinal(Arrays.copyOfRange(dataToDecrypt, 16, dataToDecrypt.length));
    } catch (Exception e) {
        throw new RuntimeException(e);
    }
}
```

I am using bouncy castle. **If I use PKCS7 padding, I get an error about erroneous padding.**

The way the AES key is encrypted: http://www.w3.org/2001/04/xmlenc#rsa-oaep-mgf1p, http://www.w3.org/2000/09/xmldsig#sha1. The way XML data is encrypted: http://www.w3.org/2001/04/xmlenc#aes128-cbc.

***Is it possible the message is randomly padded?***

------ EDIT ------

It seems that the spec uses ISO 10126 padding, use "AES/CBC/ISO10126Padding" instead of "AES/CBC/NoPadding".

Answer (score 4, accepted):

> Is it possible the message is randomly padded?

Yes, as detailed in the [Padding section](https://www.w3.org/TR/2002/REC-xmlenc-core-20021210/Overview.html#sec-Padding) it uses random padding by saying that the question marks can be of *any value*, but the last byte denotes the length of the padding. Their example: `0x2122232425262728??????????????08`.

This is actually [ISO 10126 padding](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Padding_%28cryptography%29#ISO_10126) and you can easily remove it by looking at the last byte:

```
byte[] pp = cipher.doFinal(Arrays.copyOfRange(dataToDecrypt, 16, dataToDecrypt.length));
return Arrays.copyOf(pp, pp.length - pp[pp.length-1]);
```

Note that if you're handling the padding yourself, you must use NoPadding in `alg`.

Comment: Thank you so much! I will use "AES/CBC/ISO10126Padding" which seems to work, provided you have BouncyCastle.

Comment: AES/CBC/ISO10126Padding worked with JDK 8, without Bouncy Castle

`{
 String cipherMethod = "AES/CBC/ISO10126Padding"; // This should be derived from Saml 
 AlgorithmParameterSpec iv = new IvParameterSpec(cryptoBytes, 0, 16);
 byte[] cipherBlock = Arrays.copyOfRange(cryptoBytes,16, cryptoBytes.length);
  SecretKeySpec secretSauce = new SecretKeySpec(aesSymKey, "AES");

  Cipher cipher = Cipher.getInstance(cipherMethod);
  cipher.init(Cipher.DECRYPT_MODE, secretSauce, iv);

  byte[] decrypedBytes = cipher.doFinal(cipherBlock);
  return decrypedBytes;
}`